# Definition of the surface measure in some Book

Tags: integration, measure-theory, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I am studying PDEs and in some place I found an integral integrated by **the surface measure** on M=($C^k$ - Hypersurface of $R^n$).

1)Is there any reference to see how are defined this Measure on M?

2)What is the weakest assumption for the subset M of $R^n$ in order is defined the surface measure on M? ($C^k, k=?$)

3) When M is compact; is it different from the surface integral defined in Spivak Culculus on manifolds?

4) When one consider M as Riemannian manifold with the induced metric 
then this surface measure is equal to the Riemannian measure (GriGor'yan - Heat kernels and Analysis on Manifolds)?

Thanks in advance!!